# GTM google-site-verification meta tag

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I placed GTM scripts based on [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) and realized that it place it's google-site-verification meta tag `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXX">` in `<body>` instead of `<head>`. Is it correct? It won't be a problem, but on IE it put this tag very randomly, and sometime it breaks my layout (because of selectors).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the verification method and instead of Meta tag verification, you could use for example the upload HTML file method to the root of your domain.

Follow the steps in this [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) on "Changing your verification method" section.

The process is simple, tell me if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add **meta tag** when verifying the site with GTM. Here you will be verifying ownership of the GTM container code.

If you are verifying with GTM make sure you have:

> You must have View, Edit, and Manage container-level permissions in Google Tag Manager.
>
> Place the < noscript > portion of the Tag Manager code immediately after the opening  tag of your page. If you do not, verification will fail.
>
> Use the code exactly as provided; do no modify it. If you modify it, verification will fail.

If you are using meta tag for verification then - add the code directly to HTML code.

GTM is a JAVA SCRIPT code so, the **code** you added will not come outside unless you write extra Js code to append the verification meta tag to header of the website.